# Not getting desired results when creating a list in Django/Python

Tags: python, django, list, django-forms

I've been on this issue for a few hours now and just can not seem to fix it, I want my Django save function to work exactly how my clean function works but I keep getting undesired results.

example.txt put into form ----->    #lets #try is my issue.

clean function ends up printing out ['#lets','try'], ['#lets','try'], prints two for some reason not sure why, but this is what I want, and I also want to be able to take duplicate values out of the list.

```
    def clean(self):
       data = self.cleaned_data
       regex = re.compile("\B#\w\w+")
       tweeters = data['tweets']
       split_tweets = tweeters.split()
       master_list = []
       for x in split_tweets:
         if re.search(regex, x):
            master_list.append(x)
            new_list = list(set(master_list))
         print new_list
```

save function prints out this, when I want it to get the same result as my clean function, leading to when I try to create hashtag objects with new_list in my save function it creates 3(lets, lets, try) objects instead of 2(lets, try) objects, that's why I am just using x instead of new_list. Anything that need clearing up just let me know

```
[u'#lets']
[u'#lets', u'#try']
```

save function

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    data=self.cleaned_data
    regex = re.compile("\B#\w\w+")
    cleaned_tweets = data['tweets']
    split_tweets = cleaned_tweets.split()
    obj = Tweet(tweets=data['tweets'], userprofile=self.userprofile, date=timezone.now(),)
    obj.save()
    hashtag_list = []
    for x in (split_tweets):
        if re.search(regex, x):
            print x
            hashtag_list.append(x)
            new_list = list(set(hashtag_list))
            print new_list
            obj_rel = Hashtags(users_tweet=obj, hashtag=x.replace("#", ""))
            obj_rel.save()
        else:
            return ValidationError('Something went wrong try again in a few seconds')
```

Comment: What does the `data["tweets"]` look like?

Comment: Printing twice is because it's being printed for each x in split_tweets. You need to dedent the print statement one level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating `hashtag_list` outside the loop and appending the hashtags to it. In the first iteration of the loop, the first hashtag is appended and the object is created. In the second iteration, `hashtag_list` contains both hashtags, so if you use `new_list` to create the objects, you will get two (the duplicate of the first one and the second). Either create one object per iteration, completely removing `hashtag_list`, or create the objects only after the loop, by iterating `hashtag_list`. You can use `set` on `split_tweets` to remove duplicates, or better yet, do it in the `clean` method so you don't have to deal with it in `save`.

For example:

```
for x in (split_tweets):
    if re.search(regex, x):
        hashtag_list.append(x)
new_list = set(hashtag_list)
for hashtag in new_list:        
    obj_rel = Hashtags(users_tweet=obj, hashtag=hashtag.replace("#", ""))
    obj_rel.save()
```